# DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> with INNER JOIN doesn't set base class property values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, dbcontext

Having this EF code first entity partial class.

```
public partial class Report
{
    public Guid ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SurveyDate { get; set; } 
}
```

And this partial extension.

```
public partial class Report : SyncObject
{
    public override string ObjectId
    {
        get { return ReportId.ToString(); }
        set { ReportId = Guid.Parse(value); }
    }
}
```

The SyncObject base class.

```
public class SyncObject : ISyncObject
{
    public virtual string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public long VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}
```

In the EF configuration class I ignore the SyncObject properties because they are not part of the table.

```
public partial class ReportConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Report>
{
    public ReportConfiguration()
        : this("Wind")
    {
    }

    public ReportConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".Reports");
        HasKey(x => x.ReportId);

        Property(x => x.ReportId).HasColumnName("ReportId").IsRequired().HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(x => x.Status).HasColumnName("Status").IsRequired().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.SurveyDate).HasColumnName("SurveyDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("date");
        Ignore(x => x.CorrelationId);
        Ignore(x => x.ObjectId);
        Ignore(x => x.CreateDateTime);
        Ignore(x => x.IsDeleted);
        Ignore(x => x.LastUpdateDateTime);
        Ignore(x => x.VersionNumber);
    }
}
```

We have two database tables, Reports and SyncMetadata with no foreign key in the SyncMetadata, it is needed this way for DB simplicity and supporting tables with different PK datatype.

I don't care about EF context tracking so I use the `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("QUERY").ToListAsync()`.

The query does a join between the two tables and returns all fields.

```
SELECT ReportId
      ,Status
      ,SurveyDate
      ,S.CorrelationId
      ,S.ObjectId
      ,S.VersionNumber
      ,S.CreateDateTime
      ,S.LastUpdateDateTime
      ,S.IsDeleted
  FROM Reports R
  INNER JOIN SyncMetadata S
  ON R.ReportId=S.ObjectId
```

SQL Server Management Studio works great with this query, I get the records I need with all the fields joined from the tables, but the problem is that SqlQuery doesn't append the SyncMetadata fields to the SyncObject base class properties.

Comment: Did you try using .SqlQuery to not your Domain classes, but separate sets of classes with inheritance instead? It feels like it can be using your ReportConfiguration for querying, but I cannot check this assertion right now.

Comment: @raderick You were right, I just changed the class from EF domain entity to my Data Transfer Object class and worked flawlessly! Thanks for the idea, in this case I don't even need Automapper. Post the answer and I will mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple possible reasons for this that need testing:

1. Entity Type Configurations are used when SqlQuery is executed.

According to Entity Framework CodePlex, this is not true: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233?PendingVoteId=233.

> The SqlQuery method is designed not to take any mapping into account,
>   including mapping that is applied using attributes. It simply matches
>   the column names from the results with property names in the object.
>   If the column names don't match you will need to use a column alias
>   (AS keyword in SQL Server) to rename the column in the results.

This is true for EF 6 latest version, as it states.

2. Inheritance is not handled for SqlQuery method.

You can try using .SqlQuery to not your Domain classes, but separate sets of classes with inheritance instead, if it works fine, problem is somewhere else. This might probably be a solution for you to use, if it works well.

You can always download sources and analyze them to get the solution: 
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest
Just plug it in instead of NuGet package and debug step by step to see, what place the error happens.

I strongly suggest trying to get DTO objects from SqlQuery, as you will get least side-effects here. For non-tracking domain entity queries I would recommend using Linq queries with .AsNoTracking(), if it's applicable for you.